# "fo"-ligature makes PDF code look strange in xetex

Tags: xetex, pdf

I'm trying to extract table data from a PDF. To this end, I need the precise locations of the beginning and end of a piece of text, and that's where my question comes in.
For testing, I generated some text using LaTeX. Consider the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
```

When compiled via latex  -> dvips -> ps2pdf, I get (after decompression) the following PDF code, which looks fine:

```
10 0 0 10 0 0 cm          # concat to transformation matrix
BT                        # begin text mode
/R8 9.96264 Tf            # select font
1 0 0 1 148.68 657.24 Tm  # set text matrix
[(f)3.87556(o)-29.9875(o)-5.88993]TJ
# ^ print 'f', then go a little bit left, print 'o' (so f and o
# overlap a bit), go a little bit right, print 'o'. Then go right again,
# for whatever reason.
```

But when using xelatex, it looks like this:

```
 1 0 0 1 72 720 cm  # concat a DIFFERENT transformation matrix
 0 G 0 g            # set gray levels to 0
 BT                 # begin text mode
 /F1 9.963 Tf       # select font
 76.71 -62.76 Td    # move to text position (this was missing above)
 [(fo)-28(o)]TJ     # print 'fo', then go 28 right, then print 'o'
```

What confuses me is the last line in the second output: How come that 'f' and 'o' overlap? Where is that specified? I don't see any 'Tc' commands or the such.
And then how come that the second 'o' doesn't overlap with the first one?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you add the initial shift `(72,720)` to the later shift `(76.71,-62.76)`, you get `(148.71,657.24)` which is pretty much the same thing so no issues on the trafo matrix.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I already expected something like that. What bugs me the most though is how the overlapping in "fo" is created from the second piece of code.

Comment: Try the word `fizz` (which should be corrected in both methods and maybe it helps.

Comment: This seems to be a different issue to me: "fizz" produces characters 'fi', 'z', 'z' where 'fi' is a ligature character. As it has a glyph associated, one can just retrive its width from the current font. "fo" does not have its own character, though.

Answer (score 3):

### Generating uncompressed files

Uncompressed files can be generated via TeX commands in case of pdfLaTeX or LuaLaTeX:

```
\ifx\pdfobjcompresslevel\undefined
\else
  \pdfobjcompresslevel=0
  \pdfcompresslevel=0
\fi
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document} 
foo
\end{document}
```

With XeLaTeX uncompressed files can be generated via the command line:

```
xelatex --output-driver="xdvipdfmx -V4 -z0" test
```

Route latex/dvips/ps2pdf:

```
ps2pdf -dCompressPages=false test.ps
```

### Page streams

pdfTeX:

> [image: pdfLaTeX]

```
BT
/F8 9.9626 Tf 148.712 707.125 Td [(fo)-28(o)]TJ
ET
```

LuaLaTeX:

> [image: LuaLaTeX]

```
BT
/F15 9.96264 Tf 1 0 0 1 148.712 707.125 Tm [(fo)-27(o)]TJ
ET
```

XeTeX:

> [image: xelatex]

```
 q 1 0 0 1 72 769.89 cm 0 G 0 g BT /F1 9.963 Tf 76.71 -62.76 Td[(fo)-28(o)]TJ ET
 Q
```

latex/dvips/ps2pdf:

> [image: latex/dvips/ps2pdf]

```
q 0.1 0 0 0.1 0 0 cm
/R7 gs
0 g
q
10 0 0 10 0 0 cm BT
/R8 9.96264 Tf
1 0 0 1 148.68 707.14 Tm
[(f)3.87556(o)-29.9875(o)-5.88993]TJ
ET
Q
Q
```

### Discussion

- In neither case I can't see any overlapping of the glyph shapes.
- There aren't any ligatures involved.
- Additonal space is inserted between the two `o`s. This is called implicit kerning and the data are looked up by TeX in the TFM file (`cmr10.tfm`). A negative number (−28) means that space is inserted inbetween. A positive number means that the glyph bounding boxes overlap.
- Only in the case of latex/dvips/ps2pdf the `f` and the next `o` are moved a little bit closer by 0.00387556 (unit is per mill!), introduced by Ghostscript.
- Your case of XeLaTeX differs from the finding here: `0 G 0 g` is usually added by package `color` several times. Perhaps you have used a different TeX file with a package for color and cleaned up the PDF outcome. Check, whether you are also using different fonts.